Telegram bot - kicking users using python-telegram-bot library
I want to create a bot that kicks users from group based on certain condition (doesn't matter).
My problem is - I found function that kicks users ( Bot.ban_chat_member() from python-telegram-bot ), but it kicks them based on their IDs. How to obtain someone's ID, when the only data I have is their username?
Thank you!
Tried methods from python-telegram-bot library

This question is similar to: Telegram Bot: Is it possible to get userid using username?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
